# Godot: does Engine.time_scale controls music speed

Tags: godot, gdscript

I want know if setting `Engine.time_scale` changes how fast my music is being played

Comment: No, it does not. What are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Engine.time_scale` controls how fast or slow the in-game clock ticks versus the real life one.
It does not affect the music/audio speed.

You can adjust the pitch scale of `AudioStreamPlayers` to adjust playback speed.

[image: AudioStreamPlayer]

Also if you'd like to speed up audio without changing it's pitch too much - you can try this out:
https://godotengine.org/qa/88935/how-can-i-change-speed-of-an-audio-without-changing-its-pitch